# angular, send $http post to send email via php

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to send a mail from my ionic app.

services.js:

```
.service('sendToServer', [
    '$http',
    function ($http) {
        'use strict';

        this.f = function (dataToSend) {
            return $http({
                url: 'http://id:password@boardlineapp.com/app/mail.php',
                method: "POST",
                data: dataToSend
            });
        };
    }
])
```

controller.js:

```
var data = {
                            userEmail: "john@yahoo.fr",
                            subject: " dev issue: had to fallback to local DB file",
                            destEmail: "contact@us.fr",
                            body: body
                        };

                        sendToServer
                            .f(data)
                            .success(function () {
                                console.log("Message to dev successfully sent");
                            })
                            .error(function () {
                                console.log("The message to dev could not be sent...");
                            });
```

I get the message "Message to dev successfully sent" from my code, but I don't get the email in my mailbox.

mail.php:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
if($_POST) {
    $userEmail=$_POST['userEmail'];
    $subject=$_POST['subject'];
    $destEmail=$_POST['destEmail'];
    $body=$_POST['body'];

    mail($destEmail, $subject, $body, "From:" . $userEmail);

}
?>
```

Comment: can you echo $userEmail and $subject in your php code to check that posting is successfully done?

Comment: You need to debug it somehow on PHP side

Comment: What response do you send back to the client? Also, what does mail return?

Comment: Hi, I don't know if it's the same, but have you check the mails server configuration? I was also having problems using "mail", because all my emails went straight to spam.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments, if I put echo $userEmail in mail.php, where does it display ? @Tomislav